# Can I get Eclipse File Search to include IvyDE jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, jar, ivy

The Eclipse File Search dialog doesn't seem to be playing nicely with my [IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) (2.0.0beta1) dependency jars. That is, my IvyDE brings some-dep.jar/some-dep.zip (class/source), but I don't see any way to get my file search (ctrl+h search) to include these resources when searching for text -- so if MAGIC_FLAG appears only in the Magic class inside some-dep, I won't be able to find it.

Any thoughts on how to fix/extend/make better?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a "working set" specifically to include that jar:

Ctrl-H -> File h-> Working Set (Choose) -> "Java" -> (Pick your resources and jars)

Comment: this only includes system jars (e.g., CoreAudio.jar on OSX). I don't have an option to include jars from ivyde (although they are on my build path)

Comment: Perhaps its an issue with the ivyde plugin not correctly adding its jars to the build path?

Comment: My code actually builds, though (and requires those ivyde jars to be built). My guess would be there's some mismatch in terms of what datastructures record build path issues and which record searchable stuff. Seems like a bug I should report to eclipse.